# How long ago could Jquery have been written?

Tags: jquery

If you took a time machine back in time, along with the source code for Jquery.  In what year would you not be able to use it?

In other words, in 1999 could I have sat down and written a slick web2.0 like website?

It seems like as developers we've gotten much craftier at using javascript.  But, how have the other technologies evolved to allow us to build these better mouse traps.

Comment: CW at best, this is discussion material. (Can be an interesting discussion I'm sure, but not a factual question.)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is [on topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/), it seems more *meta-*programming, than programming-related as such. But +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: If someone really were to take the jQuery source code back to say 2002, people would think that person is God `:)`

Comment: Basically the only thing that this relies on are javascript and xmlhttprequest. As long as those two technologies' specifications are similar enough to those of today's, jquery would run.

Comment: I think the correct answer is 2001 - when IE6 came out - since jQuery supports that browser... IE5 is not supported which means that it cannot run jQuery. Chrome, Firefox and Safari didn't exist back then, and the version of Opera from 2001 most likely cannot run jQuery either.

Comment: I think this could be on topic, if rephrased. He's essentially asking "What's the earliest browser that could execute jQuery code?" That's no less objective than most on-topic questions on this site.

Comment: Haha the thought of going back to 2001 and including jQuery 1.6.2 in some web-page and having it work (in IE6) is so amusing `:D`

Comment: @Benzado - rephrased it would work, but would be an open and shut question of how much value? I think it's better placed on meta where it can be discussed.

Comment: @benzado, you nailed my question.  I could not think how to word it.

Comment: @Sime Vidas, imagine how you would have been considered a coding God!!

Comment: @benzado, I tend to (broadly) agree; hence my vote-to-reopen. But I'm still...unsure of its long-term benefit/broad appeal, which is a sticking point, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://jquery.org/history/, "August 22nd, 2005 John first hints of a JavaScript library to use CSS selectors with a more succinct syntax than existing libraries: Selectors in JavaScript".

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the answer you're looking for but it's the right one: Anything written today could have been implemented on any turing-complete machine in any point in history, just like any novel written today could have been written in the past 3,000 years. Was the world ready for it or the collective mind gotten to that point? That's a different question.

Comment: That's obvious. I think what he meant was, if we traveled back in time armed only with a complete jquery source and modern day web developing experience, would we have been able to code up a modern webpage within the confines of the technologies at the time. (for example, would any browser's javascript engines be able to run jquery?)

Comment: @Razor Storm,  That is a perfect translation.  I wish I was more of a wordsmith.